# string highlight function to be case-insensitive

Tags: php, function, highlighting

I have a test highlight function to highlight portions of a string in an autocomplete output. It works great, except it is case sensitive.

As you will see below the function doesn't work properly with $term = cer because the term is located at the beginning of the plant name where it is capitalized. If I change $term = can or $term = ercis all is well.

How could I make this function more dynamic and make it case-insensitive?

FUNCTION BELOW:

```
    <?php
    $term = 'cer';
    $termHighlight = '<span style="color:#cccccc">' . $term . '</span>';
    $plant = 'Cercis canadensis';

    $plant = str_replace($term, $termHighlight, $plant);
    print_r($plant);
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance amigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well make use of [`str_ireplace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) ! This is a case-insensitive version of your `str_replace`

```
$plant = str_ireplace($term, $termHighlight, $plant);
```

Comment: Shankar Damodaran, that worked, THANK YOU VERY MUCH, will except answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Shankar, I might have been a little premature, What if I want the pic to remain Pic, as it is forcing the output to lowercase now. I tries ucfirst, but nothing happens because the first letter is the s from my <span> tag?

Comment: @BillChambers, Do `ucfirst()` here as I have shown.. `$termHighlight = '<span style="color:#cccccc">' . ucfirst($term) . '</span>';`

Comment: almost there, that works IF $term is the start of the first word, the bad thing is if a user was to search cana it would capitalize the C of the second word which shouldn't be capitalized. These are plant names so the first word is always capital and the second is not. Is there a way to do if(start of string){ucfirst}?